# Trying to write a program for Highest common factor of two numbers. But the output is showing the initialized value that is 1

Tags: java

The output is not showing the HCF but showing the initialized value that is 1.

```
package questionsOnLoops;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class hg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner srv = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter the first number: ");
        int n1 = srv.nextInt(); //first number 
        System.out.println("Enter the second number: ");
        int n2 = srv.nextInt(); //second number
        int HCF=1; // Highest Common factor
        int s; //smaller of two number
        s = Math.min(n1, n2);
        
        for(int i = s; i <= 1 ; i--) {
            if(n1%i==0&&n2%i==0) {
                HCF=i;
                break;
            }   
        }

        System.out.println(HCF);
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: 'i<=1' is wrong, needs to be i>=1 ...

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(i = 1; i <= a || i <= b; i++) {
         if( a%i == 0 && b%i == 0 )
         hcf = i;
      }
```

Use this logic. here `a` is the first number and `b` is the second.

Comment: I already did it with the increment logic. But was trying to do it this way too by using decrement in the loop.

Comment: so your condition should be i >= 1 not i <= 1

Answer (score 0):

Your code is never executing the "for" loop because you set i=s and i will never be i<=1...
Change to i>=1 and you're good to go

Answer (score 0):

You have just to change your operator in your 'for' loop.

```
for(int i = s; i >= 1 ; i--) {
```

Because in your code you loop while i is less than 1. But in your inizialization i is equal to s. So you never enter in the 'for' loop and your HCF is the default value of your HCF variable which is 1.

For your culture if you want an optimized way to calculate the HCF, you can use the Euclidean algorithm which reduce drastically the number of operation. Because you transform several division and condition into a few Euclidean division.

Here an exemple

```
public int hcf(int m, int n) {
    // the remainder of the Euclidean division
    int r = 0;

    // The algorithm says "the HCF of m and n is the last non-zero remainder"
    while(n != 0) {
        r = m % n;
        m = n;
        n = r;
    }

    return m;
}
```